# Data transformation in R- columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

My dataframe with n dates

```
Date         team_home  team_away   prob_home   draw    prob_away
01/01/2021   Brazil     Germany      95.0        5.0     0.0
01/01/2021   England    Belgium      50.0        10.0    40.0
02/01/2021   Belgium    Canada       90.0        7.0     3.0
02/01/2021   Germany    France       60.0        10.0    30.0
 ...          ....       ...         ...         ...     ...
```

DESIRED DATAFRAME. Important: Only one date per row

```
Date          prob_Brazil    draw_Brazil_Germany  prob_Germany  prob_England  draw_England_Belgium  prob_Belgium ....
01/01/2021    95.0           5.0                    0.0            50.0          10.0                40.0
02/01/2021    NA             NA                    60.0            NA              NA               90.0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you want these column names? This would create separate column names for every team most of which would remain NA.

Comment: I guess so because I need only one day per row and my current dataframe have more than one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this but the output may not be quite desirable:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(team_home, team_away), 
              values_from = c(prob_home, draw, prob_away))
```